# Ocaml / Async socket issue

Tags: asynchronous, ocaml

I am quite new to OCaml and I am working on a small TCP client utility, using Async/Core.

The connection is opened using

`Tcp.with_connection (Tcp.Where_to_connect.of_host_and_port { host = "localhost"; port = myPort })`

I need to be able to accept keyboard input, as well as read input from the socket. I use the Deferred.any for this purpose.

Calling `Reader.read reader buf` on the socket results in `Eof, which is OK, but when the method (containing the Deferred.any code) is called recursively, I get an exception:

```
“unhandled exception in Async scheduler”
(“unhandled exception”
((monitor.ml.Error
(“can not read from reader” (reason “in use”)
.....
```

`Reader.is_closed` on the reader returns false.
    How can I “monitor” the socket recursively without this exception?

Michael

Comment: I know this is very old, but you probably want to have two different Deffered's running inside the any instead of calling any recursively. You can probably `Pipe` the input from stdout into your socket output code as well.